# Tiny 11 on Raspberry Pi 3 Model B

Tags: pi-3, windows

Today I tried getting Windows 11 to run on a Raspberry Pi 3 Model B using Tiny 11.
After I downloaded Tiny 11, I downloaded and ran the Raspberry imager from [www.worproject.com](http://www.worproject.com) and put it on a micro-SD card. I put the card in the Raspberry Pi and boot it up. It took around 10 minutes but eventually Windows turned on and asked me for the time zone and keyboard language and when I clicked next I saw this screen:

[image]

When I clicked next, the Raspberry Pi rebooted and I got the same screen.
I tried connecting it to the internet using an ethernet cable which didn't help.

The tutorial used: https://www.tomshardware.com/how-to/install-tiny11-for-arm64-on-raspberry-pi-4 I am aware that the tutorial is made for a Raspberry Pi 4 but I don't see why it wouldn't work with a Raspberry Pi 3 because it has all the requirements for Tiny 11 such as being ARM64.

Comment: *what you will need: Raspberry Pi 4 **4GB** or **8GB*** - see the problem?

Comment: Yes, but by 4GB don't they mean they storage because the SD card I'm using is 64GB but if it means the ram you are right, i am using a 1GB Raspberry Pi

Comment: `don't they mean they storage` - no, absolutely not. the next line is *An 32GB or larger SSD via a USB 3 caddy. Best for performance or 16GB or larger microSD card* So, not even teh 2GB pi4 would work

Comment: Ok, thank you so much for informing me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is most likely the available memory. [Tiny 11 seem to require 2 GB RAM](https://www.msn.com/en-in/money/news/windows-11-too-heavy-for-your-ageing-pc-try-tiny11/ar-AA17NqPe), whereas Pi3 has just 1 GB.

Comment: Tiny11 claims to have run using 176MB RAM, I wonder if 2GB RAM is still required now

Comment: Yeah, I've seen it in the news too. It doesn't seem to be a simple task though. I assume one has to strip down the distribution by himself for that.

Answer (score 1):

I have done it before, just use WoR flasher and select pi 3. Its unbelievably slow and you'll need a tiny 11 install without sysreq. You can find it at https://archive.org/details/tiny-11-b-2no-sysreq.iso

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/134137)

Comment: Hello, I used the "tiny11 b2(no sysreq).iso " with the "worproject" imager and I failed to image the iso. I got the error: "The selected image file is not supported!
Please select a compatible Windows ARM64 build 18362 or newer image. (max: 25163)"